# Java dump an object

Tags: java, android, object, dump

I need to dump all the attributes of a Java object. I have found a few functions that do this but none of them handle self references and all of the functions I have found spiral into infinite recursion.

//I will be running this function on Android but that shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger and inspecting the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just for debugging or if you want some form of basic serialization take a peek at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) . Here is an example from their site talking about self references in particular...

```
Cd bj = new Cd("basement_jaxx_singles");

List order = new ArrayList();
// adds the same cd twice (two references to the same object)
order.add(bj);
order.add(bj);

// adds itself (cycle)
order.add(order);

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("cd", Cd.class);
System.out.println(xstream.toXML(order));
```

And the output is...

```
<list>
  <cd>
    <id>maria rita</id>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <id>basement_jaxx_singles</id>
  </cd>
  <cd reference="../cd[2]"/>
  <list reference=".."/>
</list>
```

Comment: I tried this and will use xstream but it does not support private fields :/

Comment: That can't be right, check this page http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html There is even the statement "XStream doesn't care about the visibility of the fields."