# Looking for standard library or technique to get pretty-printed representation of OBJECT for Java

Tags: java, dump, pretty-print

In order to understand internals of some code or print dumps on errors I use **pp**-like functions in [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) and Emacs lisp.

Now I come to to Java and look for standard library or tecnique to get pretty-printed representation of OBJECT for Java.

Seems that current Java specification allow introspection of Java object at runtime. But introspection may be not so powerful. **m(Object o)** can not be called with **new Object []** arg?

**NOTE** I am **NOT** looking to source code beautifier! I am looking for runtime pretty print Java object dumping.

**NOTE2** These questions similar but not exactly same:

- [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)
- [Best pretty-printing library for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332166/best-pretty-printing-library-for-java)
- [Java dump an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904497/java-dump-an-object)

Comment: That is a typical approach for languages as lisp and python. One sees it less for a compiled language like java. There it is setting a breakpoint and inspecting the variables in the debugger. That is not as intelligent, but you might consider altering your way of working. Implementing nice `toString`s helps too.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for tips about debuger! Do I need use some GUI debuger or jdb can nicely print class content (array of integer)? I use Emacs so it is easy store and process jdb output for me...

Comment: To print class contend under **jdb** debugger use **dump** command!

Comment: Answered by @gavenkoa. But though I can understand the clearity of Emacs, I would give an IDE a chance; there are other advantages too. NetBeans might be more simple than eclipse.

Comment: @JoopEggen I have many limitations on debug session: debugging apps without sources, deployed remotely and I want to have full debug log... I don't know how to make this in NetBeans...

Comment: Remote debugging should be possible, but without sources? I think jdb then offers best screen estate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`ReflectionToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library.

Sample:

```
String dump = ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(object);
```

As to your question:

> m(Object o) can not be called with new Object [] arg?

Sure it can, arrays of `Object` is a subtype of `Object`.

Answer (score 7):

For a quick and dirty solution to show the output of a Java object, you could use Jackson http://jackson.codehaus.org/ this will output the object in JSON.

Comment: For anyone needing further details this can be done using [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html): `(new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper()).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);`